# What's the CSS selector selenium code for the radio button?

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-rc

I am having trouble to select the radio button that has a unique span id but same radio button class, name, value and id.

```
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top; ">
  <span class ="radiobutton" id="mainId:gen_id_12e3:radiospan1e">
     <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="on" id="radio1" tabindex="0" checked>
       <label for="id-2024">Yes</label>
```

i can select the span by using this code but not able to select the radio button which is inside the span.

```
selenium.Click["css=span[id*=radiospan1e]"];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @BoltClock said.

```
selenium.Click["css=span[id*=radiospan1e] input"];
```

selects the `span` with `radiospan1e` id, then looks for an `input` child. This is where you should be learning from: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: But hey, I guess you kinda tried that one. :) Is any exception thrown? Or is the element simply not clicked?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Well the class, name, id for the radio button is same for another radio button. Like i said, it has only unique span id.

Comment: So basically you're working with a broken page... well in that case try this selector: `css=span[id*=radiospan1e] input`

Comment: Oh! Well .. that's wrong :). You know every element should have its id unique. Okay .. still easy. I'm going to edit.

Comment: @BoltClock:Awesome, BoltClock. That just worked fine. Is there any link that i can learn CSS code for clicking all the checkboxes in the table depending upon the text inside the table?

Comment: @Slanec: Thanks for your help. I went through that website but couldn't find anywhere that has the code for the radio button.Also i am trying to learn CSS code for clicking the check boxes in the table depending upon the text in another column. Is there any helpful website you can provide?

Comment: You can refer to the link that Slanec has added to the answer.

Comment: Exactly. The code we used is from [Descendants section of that page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

I think learning and understanding all the rules is essential. The link _really_ helps. Also, [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_selector#Syntax). If that doesn't help, either, try googling e.g. "css selectors tutorial".